# R: using data.table inside lapply

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a data.table:

```
> dt
id x
1  2
2  1
2  3
```

To count the data by id, I use this command:

```
> dt[, .N, by = id]
id N
1  1
2  2
```

But I have a whole list of these data tables, and I would like to do the above for each of them. How would I call lapply in this instance? I.e.:

```
lapply(list_of_dts, ??)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the same command over list of data.table

```
library(data.table)

lapply(list_of_dt, function(dt) dt[, .N, by = id])

#[[1]]
#   id N
#1:  1 1
#2:  2 2

#[[2]]
#   id N
#1:  1 1
#2:  2 2
```

**data**

```
list_of_dt <- list(structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L), x = c(2L, 1L, 3L)), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10400a0e0>), 
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L), x = c(2L, 1L, 3L)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10400a0e0>))
```

Comment: This answer is clean +1. Another short-hand that is less-clean is ```lapply(list_of_dt, '[', , .N, by = id)```.

Comment: I had tried doing something like this but couldn't get the syntax to work. Thanks.